# n-queens, checking for a valid board

Tags: backtracking, n-queens

So I'm trying to solve the n-queens problem. I think I have a valid backtracking implementation, but I think my method for checking if a board is valid is off(as well as wildly inefficient), but I can't see why. Can anyone see why / offer a better method?

```
/** Given an N x N chess board, find placements for N queens on the board such that
* none of them are attacking another queen (two queens are attacking each other if
* they occupy the same row, column, or diagonal).
* Print out the row, col coordinates for each queen on a separate line, where the
* row and column numbers are separated by a single space. */
static void solveQueens(int n) {
    boolean[][] board = new boolean[n][n];
    board = solveQueens(board, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
            if (board[i][j]) {
                System.out.printf("%s %s\n", i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
/** Returns a solved board for the n-queens problem, given an empty board. */
static boolean[][] solveQueens(boolean[][] board, int queensLeft) {
    if (queensLeft == 0) {
        return board;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
            if (board[i][j]) { continue; }
            board[i][j] = true;
            if (isValid(board)) {
                return solveQueens(board, queensLeft - 1);
            } else {
                board[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
/** True iff BOARD is a valid solution, with no queens attacking each other. */
static boolean isValid(boolean[][] board) {
    boolean occupied = false;
    //Horizontal
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (boolean queen : board[i]) {
            if (queen && occupied) {
                return false;
            }
            if (queen) {
                occupied = true;
            }
        }
        occupied = false;
    }
    //Vertical
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = board.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            boolean queen = board[j][i];
            if (queen && occupied) {
                return false;
            }
            if (queen) {
                occupied = true;
            }
        }
        occupied = false;
    }
    //Diagonals 
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
            if (board[i][j]) {
                for (int k = 0; k < board.length; k++) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < board.length; l++) {
                        if (((i - k) == (j - l)) && board[k][l] && !(k == i && l == j)) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to place a queen for each square, which is very inefficient (`2^(n*n)`), you might want to modify the second `solveQueens` function to try placing at most one queen for each row. In other words, the longer `solveQueens` function will try every possible column per row, and move on to the next row.

Another point is, the `board` variable to the second `solveQueens` function is modified in place, so we dont actually have to return it. Instead, we can simply return a `true` or `false` value to indicate if there is a solution.

So the first `solveQueens` function can be changed to:

```
static void solveQueens(int n) {
    boolean[][] board = new boolean[n][n];
    // boolean return value from second solveQueens function
    boolean solved = solveQueens(board, n);
    if (solved) {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
                if (board[i][j]) {
                System.out.printf("%s %s\n", i, j);
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.printf("No solution for board of size %d\n", n);
    }
}
```

And the second modified `solveQueens` function, which recursively goes down each row, and tries all possible columns for each row:

```
static boolean solveQueens(boolean[][] board, int row, int n) {
    // we have a queen for each row, done
    if (row >= n) {
        return board;
    }
    // for the current row, try placing a queen at column 0
    // if that fails, try placing a queen at column 1
    // if that fails, try placing a queen at column 2, and so on
    for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
        board[row][j] = true;
        if (isValid(board)) {
            // placing at (row, j) is valid, try next row
            boolean boardSolved = solveQueens(board, row + 1, n);
            if (boardSolved) {
                // board is solved, yay
                return boardSolved;
            }
        }
        // cannot place queen at (row, j) with current board configuration.
        // set board[row][j] back to false
        board[i][j] = false;
    }
    // tried every column in current row and still cant solve, return false
    return false;
}
```

For this portion of the `isValid` function:

```
//Diagonals 
for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
        if (board[i][j]) {
            for (int k = 0; k < board.length; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < board.length; l++) {
                    if (((i - k) == (j - l)) && board[k][l] && !(k == i && l == j)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return true;
```

In the innermost `if`, you will have to use `(abs(i - k) == abs(j - l))` instead of `(i - k) == (j - l)`. An example where the original code will fail is when `i = 0`, `j = 3`, `k = 3`, `l = 0` (a queen is at row 0 column 3, and a second queen is on row 3 column 0), so `(i - k) == 0 - 3 == -3` and `(j - l) == 3 - 0 == 3`, and even though these 2 queens are diagonal to each other, the innermost `if` will fail to detect it. Using `abs(i - k) == abs(j - l)` will turn the row distance (`i - k`) and column distance (`j - l`) into absolute values, and hence will work.

So just change this line:

```
if (((i - k) == (j - l)) && board[k][l] && !(k == i && l == j)) {
```

to:

```
if ((abs(i - k) == abs(j - l)) && board[k][l] && !(k == i && l == j)) {
```

and the `isValid` function should be fine.

Hope that helps!